# emacs byte compile errors on the *first* require statement

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the problem with my emacs init.el file which drives me crazy.

my init.el sets load-path to bunch of add-ins and then calls a number of requires.

Emacs loads fine and everything works but flycheck for elisp flags the first *require* statement in the init.el with "can't open load file" and if I byte compile it also gives me the same error.

I created the simplest example possible to recreate the problem and tested it on both MacOs X and Ubuntu with emacs 24.3 (9.0). both tests give me the same error.

here is the example:

```
;; init.el --- entry point for configuration

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/.")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/exec-path-from-shell")
(require 'test)
(require 'exec-path-from-shell)

;; test.el --- test lives in "~/.emacs.d"
(defvar test-var "this is test")
(provide 'test)
```

the error :

```
vagrant@elsa:~/.emacs.d$ pwd
/home/vagrant/.emacs.d
vagrant@elsa:~/.emacs.d$ sudo make
emacs --batch --eval "(byte-recompile-directory \".\" 0)"
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Checking /home/vagrant/.emacs.d...
Compiling /home/vagrant/.emacs.d/init.el...

In toplevel form:
init.el:5:1:Error: Cannot open load file: test
Checking /home/vagrant/.emacs.d/auto-save-list...
Checking /home/vagrant/.emacs.d/bin...
Checking /home/vagrant/.emacs.d/exec-path-from-shell...
Done (Total of 0 files compiled, 1 failed, 2 skipped in 2 directories)
vagrant@elsa:~/.emacs.d$
```

if I change the order of require statements ()

```
(require 'exec-path-from-shell)
(require 'test)
```

the error will become:

```
In toplevel form:
init.el:5:1:Error: Cannot open load file: exec-path-from-shell
```

what is going on? what am I doing wrong?

Regards, Roman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The byte compiler does not evaluate top-level forms normally.  `require` is a special case, but the `add-to-list` calls, which extend `load-path`, are not visible to the byte compiler.

You need to wrap them in `eval-and-compile`:

```
(eval-and-compile
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/.")
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/exec-path-from-shell"))
```

This forces the byte compiler to evaluate these calls, so the `load-path` is properly extended  at compile time.

Note that you **should not add `~/.emacs.d` to `load-path`**, and the byte compiler will warn you if you do.

You should probably just use package.el to install packages.  It'll handle all of this automatically.

Comment: thank you very much - this solves the issue. I actually use el-get to install packages but I have few libs on my own that need to be added to load-path explicitly. many thanks!

Comment: See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Eval During Compile` `RET`

Comment: I had a similar problem bugging me for ages. I was just about to post a question when Stackoverflow found this one for me. Awesome.